# Is there any hat-trick wickets taken by as a team?

Tags: cricket

In Cricket, is there any [hat-trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hat-trick#Cricket) wickets taken by as a team except the individual person's hat-trick?

Example:

> With in a over in continuous three balls as wickets - mixed of run out, caught, bowled, stumped, LBW, hit wicket and handling the ball.

or

> On any over's last two balls as wickets and next over's first ball as wicket- mixed of run out, caught, bowled, stumped, LBW, hit wicket and handling the ball.

I didn't find any reference in the internet. If any one aware of that, please share the reference link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you looked very hard ;-) A simple Google for "[cricket hat trick run outs](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=cricket+hat+trick+run+outs)" led to [this rec.sport.cricket thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rec.sport.cricket/lUlyonYHQUE) and the [Ireland vs Netherlands match in the 2011 World Cup](http://www.espncricinfo.com/icc_cricket_worldcup2011/engine/match/433595.html?innings=1;view=commentary) which had *four* run outs in consecutive balls in the last four balls of the innings:

> 49.3 AF Buurman run out 26 (49m 30b 4x4 0x6)
>
> 49.4 PM Seelaar run out 0 (1m 1b 0x4 0x6)
>
> 49.5 Adeel Raja run out 0 (1m 0b 0x4 0x6)
>
> 49.6 Mudassar Bukhari run out 11 (22m 8b 0x4 1x6)

Given that, it doesn't seem too unlikely there are going to be quite a lot of these incidents out there.

Answer (score 1):

Such an incident of a team hat-trick happened in the final of the 2016 Big Bash League. Melbourne Stars who were batting first, lost 3 wickets in the last 3 balls of the innings. [Here is the match report of the final.](http://www.espncricinfo.com/big-bash-league-2015-16/engine/current/match/897763.html)

- Adam Zampa was the first to be the run out from a direct hit on the stumps.
- Evan Gulbis was caught out off the next ball.
- Daniel Worrall was run-out off the last ball by the wicket-keeper.

The team picked up 3 wickets, although Clint McKay was only credited with the one in the middle. [Here is a video of the three wickets taken in three successive balls.](http://www.cricket.com.au/video/thunder-team-hat-trick-kfc-big-bash-league-final-highlights-sydney-thunder-melbourne-stars/2016-01-24)

Answer (score 1):

In **2016 T20 world cup** this happen to India, during the group match against Bangladesh.

here is the link [of that match](http://www.espncricinfo.com/icc-world-twenty20-2016/engine/match/951353.html?innings=1;view=commentary)